# How are special characters encoded in tag-URL?

Tags: tags

I am trying to get the right link to `Tag-Pages/Archives` with JS out of the tag name.

For the tag "`abc`" I can use `?tag=abc`.
But for "`$$`" neither `?tag=$$` nor `?tag=%24%24` (used `encodeURIComponent`) work.

I know I could use the tag's term_id, but in my context, I don't know the term_id and would have to do a separate ajax call just to get it, which seems not very elegant...

Does an encoding exist, which allow getting to the tags page of "`$$`"?

Comment: WordPress has its own php sanitization functions. Also keep in mind that users are free to set a term’s slug separately from the name.

Comment: yes you're right, they can change the slug. Than I can not avoid the call and the question is obsolete